# Quick filter doesnt show right results when I filter date field whose format I changed to \Wyyww

Tags: ms-access, date-formatting, ms-access-2016

I changed the format to date fields to "W"yyww, and the results show as expected. However, when I try to use the quick filter to show all data for a specific week, it only shows data for one day of the week and disregards the rest.

For example, I filter the data to show W1940, but it only shows data for one of the days in the week.

This happens when I try to filter on the table, related query, and form.

How can I get around this?

Comment: Did you format with format property or Format function? Format property does not change stored value. Actual value will be used. Edit question to post your query and/or VBA as text, not image.

Comment: I used format property, no code was used. Should I use a function then?

Comment: Suggest you try it. I am surprised query even runs. Edit question if you need more help.

Comment: I've tried using this: FormatDateTime([DATE_RELEASED];"[yyww]") but its not working, could you help me with the function? I need to write this in the query, is that right?

Comment: Use [Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications) not [FormatDateTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/formatdatetime-function)

Comment: Its showing me the correct format now, but the problem now is that it changed the stored value; you cant see the specific date. I need this field to remain a Date/Time field since the user will use this to enter specific date in form. So data entry should be in Date/Time format and it should show as Wyyww, not string.

Comment: Where is the format? Table, query or form control? Using last, you can see and add the original date format if set focus on control.

Comment: I think I'm a bit lost, can you clarify? If I change the format in the form on the property sheet, then the quick filters dont work properly (dont recognize all days in week).. Is that what you meant I do? Or should I put the function somewhere else? I tried putting it in the query in design view for the field.

Comment: Use 2 fields in query. One with format (to filter) , one without(to edit date)

Comment: Is that the only way to do this? I was trying to avoid multiple fields since there are many date fields that will need to be modified.

Comment: I got it wrong;( Use format on query (`Select ...., Format([DateField],"yyww") as YearWeekNr, .....`Edit are done on same control? That would be not trivial then (adjust `Me.Filter`on `Form_ApplyFilter` e.g.). That won't change the stored value, but can be filtered. For edits you need a control without query format (e.g overlay the formated control on dblclick)..Use`debug.Print Me.Filter`to see what is going wrong.